# IAM role and Keys setup for S3 AWS accessing two different account buckets using boto3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, python-3.6, boto3

I have two different accounts
 1) Account one which is vendor account and they gave us AccessID and secret key for access. 
2) Our Account where we have full access.

We need to copy files from Vendor S3 bucket to Our S3 bucket using boto3 Python 3.7 scripts.

What is the best function in boto3 to use to get best performance.

I tried using get_object and put_object. Problem with this scenario is I am actually reading the file body and writing it. How do we just copy from one account to another account with the faster copy mode?

Is there any setup I can do from my end to directly copy. We are okay to use Lambda as well as long as I get good performance. I cannot request any changes from vendor except that they give us access keys.

Thanks
Tom

Answer (score 1):

One of the fastest ways to copy data between 2 buckets is to use S3DistCp, worth to use it only if you have a lot of files to copy, it will copy them in a distributed way with an EMR cluster.
Lambda function with boto3 will be an option, only if copy takes less then 5 minutes if longer you can consider using ECS tasks (basically Docker containers).

Regarding the part how to copy with boto3 you can check [here](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.copy).
Looks like that you can do something like:

```
import boto3

s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
s3_resource = boto3.resource('s3')

source_bucket_name = 'src_bucket_name'
destination_bucket_name = 'dst_bucket_name'

paginator = s3_client.get_paginator('list_objects')
response_iterator = paginator.paginate(
    Bucket=source_bucket_name,
    Prefix='your_prefix',
    PaginationConfig={
        'PageSize': 1000,
    }
)
objs = response_iterator.build_full_result()['Contents']

keys_to_copy = [o['Key'] for o in objs] # or use a generator (o['Key'] for o in objs)

for key in keys_to_copy:
    print(key)
    copy_source = {
        'Bucket': source_bucket_name,
        'Key': key
    }
    s3_resource.meta.client.copy(copy_source, destination_bucket_name, key)
```

The proposed solution first get the name of the objects to copy, then it calls the copy command for each object.
To make it faster instead of using a for loop, you can use async.

If you run the code in a Lambda or ECS task remember to create a IAM role with access to both Source Bucket and Destination bucket.

Comment: Hi, How do I mention the destination bucket name. I mean dont I have to connect to destination bucket name before copying it into that folder. As mentioned earlier, my source and destination are different accounts and different buckets. Destination bucket I do have access keys. I am running this python script in EC2 instance

Comment: The destination bucket is specified in the code `destination_bucket_name = 'dst_bucket_name'`. If you are running the code from an EC2 machine, you don't need to specify any AWS keys,  just create an Instance profile role (and attach it to the machine) with the permission to access the destination bucket. Also ask to your vendor to give read access to the source bucket to your AWS account, then delegate this policy to the instance profile of your machine. Check here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-walkthroughs-managing-access-example2.html

Comment: Hi, Thank you about that. I have secret , access keys for my bucket. What command do I use, I don't want to read into buffer(EC2) and then copy it into my S3 bucket. As explained : s3_vendor_connection, s3_our_connection. Then reading s3_vendor.get_object(), then s3_our.put_object().  I am trying to put it straight away into out bucket without get and put. Is it good to get() and put(). Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately, the only solution that comes to my mind using aws secretes, is the one that you suggested in the beginning. Download the S3 objects from the source bucket, then upload the objects again to the destination bucket, that is really inefficient. Is there any possibility to convince the vendor to attach an S3 GetObject policy to your AWS account? This will be the best solution so far. Check this out https://blog.vizuri.com/how-to-copy/move-objects-from-one-s3-bucket-to-another-between-aws-accounts Is pretty much what you want to do, but they use aws cli (that is written in boto3)

Comment: So based on my understanding, if we are not using CLI then other best solution is to create IAM role which can read vendor bucket and write to our S3 bucket? Is that correct.

Comment: There are 2 operations to do:
- create a IAM role with read permission to the source bucket and write permission to destination bucket
- ask the vendor to give your AWS account read permission to the objects in the bucket (this is done use the AWS Principal concept)