# Cross-account S3 bucket permissions

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm trying to grant access to S3 bucket to other account using S3 UI:

`Permissions -> Access Control List -> Access for other AWS accounts`

I know canonical id for account I want to grant permissions. It is 161 char code. When I'm trying to add It I'm getting next error:

[image: canonical id error]

I'm pretty sure I'm using the correct ID because it says says `Canonical user ID (for Amazon S3)`
What is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You are probably using the wrong id. Please have a look at this document to find out how to retrieve the one that you need here: [AWS account identifiers - AWS General Reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/acct-identifiers.html)

Having that said, in most cases it would be better to not use access control list but access S3 via cross-account roles instead. To learn more, please have a look at: [Provide Cross-Account Access to Objects In S3 Buckets](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cross-account-access-s3/)

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to grant bucket access to another AWS Account, I would recommend using a **Bucket Policy**. This allows the user(s) in the other account to use their normal credentials to access the bucket.

Here is a sample bucket policy that grants access to a specific user in another AWS account:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Action": [
        "s3:GetObject",
        "s3:ListBucket"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket",
        "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/*"
        ],
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": [
          "arn:aws:iam::ACCOUNT-ID:user/foo"
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```